# An unwanted line on Tab bar controller under ios7

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Under iOs7, and not earlier versions, I've a line who pass through my Tab Bar (shown with green arrow on example picture from the link below).

I don't know where the problem come from. Any idea how to correct it ?

Thank you very much.

[image: Tab Bar with a line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to check the height of UITabBar in iOS 7. It is possible Apple has decreased the height of UITabBar, as per height of UITabBar you have to redesign your image for accurate result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems exact the height of UITabBar as been decreased. No method to hide this line ?

Comment: To hide that line you must have to resize your background image of UITabbar specially for iOS 7 as per new height of UITabBar & programmatically you have to check that if (iOS 7) then setup iOS7-navigationbarbgimage image else iOS6-navigationbarbgimage, i think it should be proper solution i guess.

Comment: I have chosen this method and redone my background images to stuch to the UITabbar. Thx.

Comment: One Property has been added from iOS 7 i.e barStyle update that property to UIBarStyleBlack.

Comment: and then set up shadow image like this [tabBar setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];

Comment: Hi @Mur.. I am facing the same issue.. Do i have to get my new image made with dimensions 320X49 pixels?? At present i am using 320X64 pixels, which seem to bring a line in the middle of my image..

Comment: Yes, You have to update your image size as tabBar height is 49 pts.

Answer (score 11):

If you're referring to the couple of pixel shadow on top of the bar, it's easy to remove. All you have to do is enable clipsToBounds on your tab bar, like so:

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The line I don't want is not the 2 pixels of shadow but the 1 pixel line who pass through the buttons, right where the green arrow is. But your information was useful to see that this line was the bounds of the tab bar... Can't this line be hidden ? I can reduce the buttons but I would want the home button higher...

Comment: Same problem with me, this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160096/an-unwanted-line-on-tab-bar-controller-under-ios-8-1-in-iphone-6  , i have use your way but its not working , i have add snapshot of my screen in question please check it and tell me something....Please

Answer (score 5):

Add these two line after you create the TabBar

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];

Great answer works for me!!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentImage.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

/////transparentImage.png - empty 1x1px image
//// It's resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

use this
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentImage.png"]];

transparentImage.png can be image with 0 alpha size 1x1 pixel

Comment: Thank you but I've already followed advice of @brij and changed my images.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are struggling with a custom UITabBarItem taller than the UITabBar height, a solution that let you preserve your default UITabBar shadowImage and backgroundImage (with the blur effect) is achieved by using CALayer.

I am using this code in my UITabBarController subclass:

```
- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.delegate = self;

        CALayer * superLayer = self.tabBar.layer;
        CALayer * layer = [CALayer layer];
        layer.bounds = CGRectMake (0.0f, 0.0f, 62.0f, 56.0f);
        layer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed: @"custom-tabbaritem"].CGImage;
        layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5f, 1.0f);
        layer.position = CGPointMake (superLayer.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, superLayer.bounds.size.height);
        layer.zPosition = 1.0f;
        [self.tabBar.layer addSublayer: layer];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Note that you can also use `layer.frame = CGRectMake (...)` in place of `bounds`, `anchorPoint` and `position`. I am using these ones to better deal with images with various heights by anchoring the sublayer to the bottom of the `UITabBar`.
By implementing a UITabBarControllerDelegate method such as `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` it is possible to make this `UITabBarItem` do custom actions, for example presenting a modal view controller.

In this case I used a plain `UIViewController` as the view controller for the custom `UITabBarItem` (the other ones are all subclasses):

```
- (BOOL)  tabBarController: (UITabBarController *) tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController
{
    if ([viewController isMemberOfClass: [UIViewController class]])
    {
        SomeViewController * modal = [SomeViewController new];
        [tabBarController presentViewController: modal
                                       animated: YES
                                     completion: nil];
        modal = nil;

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, I'll try it for another project.