# ios7 forced translucient tabbar

Tags: ios6, ios7, interface-builder, uitabbar

3.5" ios7:

[image: 3.5 ios7]

3.5" ios 6:

[image: 3.6 ios6]

4" ios7:

[image: 4 ios7]

I want an Opaque tab bar and I have set it everywhere I think:

At tab bar:

[image: tab bar]

At Navigation controllers: - **unchecked the translucient**

[image]

In 4" I don't have the translucent forced. how can I escape at 3.5" , ios7 version?

Edit:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18786414/529543) method doesn't work.

Edit2:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19052387/529543) solution doesn't work either.

Edit3:

[Neither this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19093329/529543)

Edit 4: 
I think this is a bug in ios, I don't know where to dig anymore, because the changes made looks like this:

3.5" ios 6.1  - observe the upper part line removed:

[image: 3.5" ios6.1]

4" ios 7: - observer the upper part: completely black - as how it is the background image bottom part.

[image: 40 ios7]

The 3.5" ios 7 still the same! What to do? :(

**At .plist there is a "Nib file base name: MainVindow.**
And there I have set the TabBarController  and is linked to AppDelegate. At `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I am doing this settings. Maybe elsewhere should be?

```
 if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")){
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setClipsToBounds:YES];

        UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentImage.png"];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:tabBarBackground];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];

        UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
        tabBar.tintColor  = [UIColor yellowColor];
        tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    }


    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

- no effect if I move the code to: `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set background image. It worked for me.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [UITabBar appearance];
[tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar-background"]];
```

Comment: added at edit this doesn't work for me: 
`UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentImage.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];` Not for 3.5" ios 7 , for other yes

Comment: I got where is the problem, I have solved, so I want to close the question. NOT THIS WAS THE SOLUTION!!!