# Unwanted line on tab bar on iPhone 6

Tags: swift, ios8, uitabbar

Under iOS 8.1 a 1px line is showing on my tab bar. This problem is only present on iPhone 6. Here's [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785930/an-unwanted-line-on-tab-bar-controller-under-ios7) with the same problem. Here is a screenshot of my tab bar.

[image]

I am using this code in Swift for my tab bar.

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "tabbar_shadow.png")
tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
tabBarController?.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
tabBarController?.tabBar.translucent = true
```

This is working fine but a 1px line is showing up above the tab bar on iPhone 6.

Comment: Did you try the solutions from the other post? Especially `tabBarController?.tabBar.setClipsToBounds = true`

Comment: i use this code but tab bar line is not hidden and tab bar background is not stay transparent

Comment: @zisoft I added http://s5.postimg.org/oh6rmuf13/screen.png image URL to explain my problem . This problem in iPhone 6

Comment: is there any solution for this??